# MySQL Optimization: DISTINCT too slow

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mariadb, database-administration

I have a query with the form

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM 
   table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6
where (several conditions to join the tables)
```

Which takes a few minutes to execute (the resulting count is 2000 million).

The problem is that when I add a DISTINCT like here:

```
SELECT COUNT(  DISTINCT field1, field2, field3, field4, field5   )
FROM 
   table1, table2, table3, table4, table5, table6
where (several conditions to join the tables)
```

The execution goes to more than 3 hours.

The problem seems to be on the DISTINCT operation, since the JOIN conditions are the same on both versions. Is there any way to optimize the execution of the DISTINCT version?

Thank you!

Comment: What aren't you using proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax?  In almost all cases like this, the problem is that the `JOIN` conditions are not set up properly.

Comment: Because it is generated code by a proprietary ETL...

Comment: Anyways, if the problem where de JOIN conditions, the slowness problem would show on both versions.

Comment: What says the optimizer. Post your EXPLAINS

Comment: You'll need to be more specific about the columns you are comparing with DISTINCT. Are they coming from the same table, different ones? By the way, 3 hours doesn't sound that bad for a 2-billion rows comparison).

Comment: Without schemas, query plans etc. we're just guessing...but my guess is the obvious: by using DISTINCT, you're forcing the database to inspect every one of the 2000 million results for uniqueness.

Answer (score 2):

> Which takes a few minutes to execute (the resulting count is 2000 million).

In order to process the `count(distinct)`, MySQL is going to have to sort 2 BILLION rows.  That is a lot of data.

It takes lots and lots of time.  There is not much you can do about it, unless you can revise the query so the intermediate data is not so large.

Answer (score 1):

Without changing the SQL statement, or without changing the structure of the tables (for example, adding some indexes, or some new intermediate summary tables), then there's probably no way to get the DISTINCT version of the query to run faster.

Likely the "big rock" in terms of elapsed time is the "Using filesort" operation. We use `EXPLAIN` to see the query execution plan; that's a quick first step for us to get a handle on what operations MySQL is performing, in what order.

There's some system parameters in MySQL and MariaDB that can be tweaked, for example allocating more memory for temporary sets to be held in MEMORY before spilling to disk; but its unlikely that there's a magic tweak that is going to fix a performance problem with 2 billion rows. And there's always the option of throwing more better hardware at the problem.

If you would be open to changing the SQL statement, or running multiple statements, then there might be an opportunity for tuning.

Answer (score 0):

Did u tried to make left join with new select statment that have discintic word alone?

Comment: In MySQL, outer joins are not possible with the old-school comma syntax for joins. And  OP provides no evidence of an attempt to re-write the SQL text, so I can pretty safely assume that the answer to your question is "no".